# Categorizing Listings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

Is it possible to group listings by type?

I have a document with two types of listings, namely one for source-code and one for series of shell-commands (and their outputs).

So is it possible to have `\lstlistingname` refer to one type as "listing" and the other as "shell-transcript"? Ideally I would also like to seperate these types in the `\lstlistoflistings` for each type. (Similar to what `\printbibliography[type=book]` does - So I would end up with one list of listings of actual source-code and one for the shell-demonstrations)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You can use `\lstnewenvironment` to define specific listing environments for any programming language and as such provide a new `\lstlistingname` in the starter code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a separate listing environment for `shell-scripts` with a specific name is quite easy, see the `\lstnewenvironment` code.

More difficult is the splitting of the `.lol` and `.los` settings: `\lst@MakeCaption` must be redefined and changed to use `los` instead of `lol`.

Please note: The current version does not work well with `hyperref` due to the anchors!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\newcounter{shelllistcntr}[section]

\makeatletter
\def\lst@MakeOtherCaption#1{%
  \lst@ifdisplaystyle
  \ifx #1t%
  \ifx\lst@@caption\@empty\expandafter\lst@HRefStepCounter \else
  \expandafter\refstepcounter
  \fi {lstlisting}%
  \ifx\lst@label\@empty\else \label{\lst@label}\fi
  \let\lst@arg\lst@intname \lst@ReplaceIn\lst@arg\lst@filenamerpl
  \global\let\lst@name\lst@arg \global\let\lstname\lst@name
  \lst@ifnolol\else
  \ifx\lst@@caption\@empty
  \ifx\lst@caption\@empty
  \ifx\lst@intname\@empty \else \def\lst@temp{ }%
  \ifx\lst@intname\lst@temp \else
  \addcontentsline{los}{lstlisting}\lst@name
  \fi\fi
  \fi
  \else
  \addcontentsline{los}{lstlisting}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thelstlisting}\lst@@caption}%
  \fi
  \fi
  \fi
  \ifx\lst@caption\@empty\else
  \lst@IfSubstring #1\lst@captionpos
  {\begingroup \let\@@vskip\vskip
    \def\vskip{\afterassignment\lst@vskip \@tempskipa}%
    \def\lst@vskip{\nobreak\@@vskip\@tempskipa\nobreak}%
    \par\@parboxrestore\normalsize\normalfont % \noindent (AS)
    \ifx #1t\allowbreak \fi
    \ifx\lst@title\@empty
    \lst@makecaption\fnum@lstlisting{\ignorespaces \lst@caption}
    \else
    \lst@maketitle\lst@title % (AS)
    \fi
    \ifx #1b\allowbreak \fi
    \endgroup}{}%
  \fi
  \fi
}

\AtBeginDocument{%    
\lstnewenvironment{shellstuff}[1][]{%
  \let\lst@MakeCaption\lst@MakeOtherCaption%
  \let\c@lstlisting\c@shelllistcntr% Use the other counter
  \let\thelstlisting\theshelllistcntr% Use a different counter format if really needed
  \lstset{language={bash},#1}% Define the language etc. 
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Shell stuff}%
}{%
}
}

\newcommand{\lstshellscriptlistingname}{List of Shell Scripts}

\newcommand{\lstshellscriptlistings}{% The `\tableofshellscripts` ;-)
  \bgroup
  \let\contentsname\lstshellscriptlistingname%
  \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{los}}%
  \tableofcontents \egroup
}


\makeatother



\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings
\lstshellscriptlistings
\begin{shellstuff}[caption={Foo shell}]
  rm *.*
  ls -l
  echo ``Ooops''
\end{shellstuff}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={C},caption={Hello world}]
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Update with 'limited' `hyperref` support and `addition to Toc`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifclassprovideschapter

\@ifundefined{chapter}{%
  \global\classprovideschapterfalse
  \newcounter{shelllistcntr}[section]
}{%
  \global\classprovideschaptertrue
  \newcounter{shelllistcntr}[chapter]
}

\makeatother


\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\def\lst@MakeOtherCaption#1{%
  \lst@ifdisplaystyle
  \ifx #1t%
  \ifx\lst@@caption\@empty\expandafter\lst@HRefStepCounter \else
  \expandafter\refstepcounter
  \fi {shelllistcntr}%
  \ifx\lst@label\@empty\else \label{\lst@label}\fi
  \let\lst@arg\lst@intname \lst@ReplaceIn\lst@arg\lst@filenamerpl
  \global\let\lst@name\lst@arg \global\let\lstname\lst@name
  \lst@ifnolol\else
  \ifx\lst@@caption\@empty
  \ifx\lst@caption\@empty
  \ifx\lst@intname\@empty \else \def\lst@temp{ }%
  \ifx\lst@intname\lst@temp \else
  \addcontentsline{los}{lstlisting}\lst@name
  \fi\fi
  \fi
  \else
  \addcontentsline{los}{lstlisting}%
  {\protect\numberline{\theshelllistcntr}\lst@@caption}%
  \fi
  \fi
  \fi
  \ifx\lst@caption\@empty\else
  \lst@IfSubstring #1\lst@captionpos
  {\begingroup \let\@@vskip\vskip
    \def\vskip{\afterassignment\lst@vskip \@tempskipa}%
    \def\lst@vskip{\nobreak\@@vskip\@tempskipa\nobreak}%
    \par\@parboxrestore\normalsize\normalfont % \noindent (AS)
    \ifx #1t\allowbreak \fi
    \ifx\lst@title\@empty
    \lst@makecaption\fnum@lstlisting{\ignorespaces \lst@caption}
    \else
    \lst@maketitle\lst@title % (AS)
    \fi
    \ifx #1b\allowbreak \fi
    \endgroup}{}%
  \fi
  \fi
}


\AtBeginDocument{%
\lstnewenvironment{shellstuff}[1][]{%
  \let\lst@MakeCaption\lst@MakeOtherCaption%
  \let\c@lstlisting\c@shelllistcntr%
  \let\thelstlisting\theshelllistcntr%
  \renewcommand{\theHlstlisting}{shelllist.\theshelllistcntr}%
  \lstset{language={bash},#1}%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Shell stuff}%
}{%
}
}

\newcommand{\lstshellscriptlistingname}{List of Shell Scripts}

\newcommand{\lstshellscriptlistings}{%
  \bgroup
  \let\contentsname\lstshellscriptlistingname%
  \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{los}}%
  \tableofcontents 
  \egroup
}


\makeatother



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\lstlistoflistings
\lstshellscriptlistings

\clearpage

\begin{shellstuff}[caption={Foo shell}]
  rm *.*
  ls -l
  echo ``Ooops''
\end{shellstuff}

\clearpage

\begin{lstlisting}[language={C},caption={Hello world}]
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}

  \begingroup
  \section*{Foo}
  \@starttoc{los}
  \endgroup
}
```

Comment: Thanks, only one small remark: the list of shell listings doesn't get added to my table of contents (Im using a KOMA-Class with `listof=totoc`)

Comment: @MalteJ: Well, that was not in your question! That's why we like to have a compilable document by the O.P. in advance.

Comment: Sorry about that (As you can see I already accepted your answer to my original question ;)) I managed to manually add it via `\addcontentsline`, which works fine.

Comment: @MalteJ: See the update at the end